# Player command failed: Premium required. However i have premium

Tags: spotipy

Im am using a family account (premium) and this code returns a'Premium required' error. My code is as follows:

```
device_id = '0d1841b0976bae2a3a310dd74c0f3df354899bc8'

def playSpotify():

    client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='<REDACTED>', client_secret='<REDACTED>')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

    playlists = sp.user_playlists('gh8gflxedxmp4tv2he2gp92ev')

    #while playlists:
        #for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
            #print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['uri'],  playlist['name']))
        #if playlists['next']:
            #playlists = sp.next(playlists)
        #else:
            #playlists = None




    #sp.shuffle(true, device_id=device_id)
    #sp.repeat(true, device_id=device_id)
    sp.start_playback(device_id=device_id, context_uri='spotify:playlist:4ndG2qFEFt1YYcHYt3krjv')
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `SpotifyClientCredentials` the token that is generated doesn't belong to any user but to an app, hence the error message.

What you need to do is use `SpotifyOAuth` instead. So to initialize spotipy, just do:

```
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth())
```

This will open a browser tab and require you to sign in to your account.

Comment: it means every user must have the premium account for it